# VBA Web Scraping, SPAN issue

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Im currently trying to scrape some data from a website utilizing but having a complete block on this.

My VBA code is as follows;

```
Sub WISE()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
Dim WPage As String
WPage = "www.thencc.org.uk/Our_Members/MemDetails.aspx?CompID=AAA-01-01"

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate WPage

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to " & WPage
DoEvents
Loop

Dim hlpe As String
'Clearly missing something

 hlpe = _
 HTML.getElementsByTagName("span").getElementsByTagName("b").innerText

 Range("a5").Value = hlpe

Set IE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""

End Sub
```

The website HTML details which i'm trying to get sits in the below;
Essentially i was going to pull the lot then parse in excel, ideally i want the address / Number.

```
 <span id="MainContent_lblDetails"><table class=tabLayout width='90%'> <tr><td style='height:20px'><b>AA Autovan Leisure Ltd</b><br/><br/>Servicing and repairs – mobile specialists in servicing and repairing touring caravans and motorhomes.  Contact us for more information<br/><br/>7 Sycamore Lane, Holmfirth, Huddersfield, HD9 7RT<br/>West Yorkshire, England<br/><br/><b>Tel - </b>01484 683636<br/><b>Web - </b><a href='http://www.aaautovanleisure.com' style='color:#0061a0' target='_blank'>www.aaautovanleisure.com</div></td></tr><tr><td align='right'><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)' style='color:#0061a0'> Back </a></td></tr></table></span>
```

Comment: Since you have the span ID, use getElementById instead --> `HTML.getElementById("MainContent_lblDetails")`.  Then get the innerText for this element, and parse accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can parse text related to the element,  but we want to use its html so as to have useful delimiters to split on. Also, we can do away with the slow browser opening and issue an XMLHTTP GET request.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim sResponse As String, HTML As New htmldocument, arrayItems() As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.thencc.org.uk/Our_Members/MemDetails.aspx?CompID=AAA-01-01", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))

    With HTML
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        arrayItems = Split(.querySelector("#MainContent_lblDetails").outerHTML, "<BR>")
        Debug.Print "Address: " & arrayItems(4) & Chr$(32) & arrayItems(5)
        Debug.Print Replace$(Replace$(Replace$(arrayItems(7), "<B>", vbNullString), "</B", vbNullString), "- >", vbNullString)
    End With
End Sub
```